# URL rewrite not working in higher environment (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, iis-10

Below url rewrite is working fine in devlopment but when it is moved to test environment the rewrite not working, giving error as (index):23 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in console. not loading the webpage properly

Not sure what is causing the issue

```
 <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect to Landing Page" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="uat." />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/somepage" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://uat.mypage.com" appendQueryString="false" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
```

Comment: in my opinion, this is a jquery script error. do you have any jquery in your page? and please provide full error message snapshot. if you have jquery in your could you need to add a reference. which type of application or site you are using?

Comment: i have jquery but after adding the URL rewrite rule only i am facing issue. if i disable the rule it works fine. Type of Application is ASP.Net(MVC)

Comment: could you please share your jquery code and detail error message snapshot?